# Strange text appearing before meta description in search results page

Tags: search

So I did a search for a site that we look after and there are some strange characters before it. I've done a search for those characters in particular and they've appeared in other results around the web on various different pages, none of which seems to have anything noticeably wrong with them. Any help on this please?

See red highlighted box below in image.

[image: A page with a description that is displaying strange characters before it.]

Answer (score 4):

After some investigation it turns out that this is a problem with Google Maps. The red pin pointer is inserting some text on the page which is getting pulled into search results so it's not really something that can be fixed until Google look into it. Oh well.

Comment: Aside: I assume you're the same user as the question asker - but you seem to be connected as a different user?

Comment: To add to @w3d's comment, you can ask for your accounts to be merged using [this form](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/contact) (linked as "contact us" from the bottom of each page here).

Comment: Yeah I am, oops! Sorry about that. It is me.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Look, it is not only happening to you. It may be some bug. You can report it directly on [Google Webmaster Forum](http://productforums.google.com/d/forum/webmasters).